# How to plot a simple dataframe with different variables with different colors

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

Good morning everyone, my problem is the graphic representation of a dataframe. My data frame is similar to this one shown below

```
     Country  Year    average_man      average_woman
0         I1  2015       9.500000           3.663500
1         I1  2016       8.000000           4.810500
2         I2  2015      12.181818           3.514545
3         I2  2016      14.727273           2.815000
```

I would like to represent all the information reported in a single graph but I wouldn't know how to assign more variables to the same axis.
Now I have tried to plot *average_men* and *country* but I cannot assign a different color to each point for each year. 
For example blue for 2015 and red for 2016.

My plot:

[image: my plot]

My code:

```
plt.scatter(df['average_man'], df['average_woman'], cmap= df['Year'])

plt.show()
```

Expected output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Method 1, to plot individual columns
# a scatter plot 
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='average_man',y='average_woman',color='red')
plt.show()

# Method 2, To plot all columns separately
df.plot(subplots=True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

#Method 3, preferred
data = np.random.rand(10,4)
data[:,0]= np.arange(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["X", "A", "B", "C"])
axis = df.plot(x="X", y="A", kind="bar")
df.plot(x="X", y="B", kind="bar", ax=axis, color="C2")
df.plot(x="X", y="C", kind="bar", ax=axis, color="C3")
plt.show()
```

Comment: if I try x='average_man' and y='country' I get TypeError: no numeric data to plot

Comment: check the data type of `df['average_man']` and `df['average_woman']`

Comment: they are both decimals

Comment: change the type by using `df["average_man"] = pd.to_numeric(df["average_man"])`

Comment: look the expected output

Answer (score 0):

I've made a dictionary that associates colors to countries:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# read csv
df = pd.read_csv('test2.txt', delim_whitespace=True)

# find all unique countries, which shall correspond to a color
countries = df['Country'].unique()
custom_colors = ['r','b','g','orange']

# create a dictionary associating a color to a country
col_dict = {country:custom_colors[i] for i, country in enumerate(countries)}

# extend dataframe by new column with country colors
df['country_colors'] = [col_dict[country] for country in df['Country']]


# plot scatteplot while using c= as a container for colors.
# This is what makes scatter special: color argument can be a container
# of many different colors
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,4))

X,Y,col = df['average_man'], df['Country'], df['country_colors']
ax.scatter(X,Y,c=col)
```

The comments of my code should explain everything. But the general idea is to find all unique countries, associate a color to all unique countries and then append a new column to the DataFrame with the right colors at the right positions: e.g. all rows with 'I1' have the color 'r' in the dataframe.